# What are the contents of the Headers in Control,Redo log and data file in a typical Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle10g

Where can i find the contents  contents of the Headers in Control,Redo log and data file in a typical Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/index-block-dumps-and-treedumps-part-i-knock-on-wood/) tells you how to dump an Oracle database block.

There's some good information in [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/confessions/why-oracle-works-the-way-it-does-4-data-blocks-part-2-9094), which is a subset of ["Confessions of an IT Hitman"](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/confessions/post-index-how-oracle-works-10605)

I haven't seen any actual reference on a physical layout - lots of bits and pieces scattered hither and yon over the net.